# Objects are not valid as a react component. (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, json, react-native

There are multiple questions with the same title but for some reason my case is simple but yet I'm unable to fix it.

I've an API which provides this response:

```
{
   "customer":{
      "default_address":{
         "address1":null,
         "city":null,
         "country":null,
         "first_name":"Chaudhry",
         "user_id":1234,
         "last_name":"Talha",
         "name":"Chaudhry Talha",
         "phone":"12345667",
         "province":null,
         "zip":"12345"
      }
   }
}
```

Which I'm storing in a state:

```
...
    const [customerInfo, setCustomerInfo] = useState({});
...
    setCustomerInfo(response.customer.default_address)
...
```

I get this error:

> Objects are not valid as a react component. (found: object with keys
> {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array
> instead.

Based on a solution I changed  `useState` to:

```
const [customerInfo, setCustomerInfo] = useState([]);
```

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
> {user_id, first_name, last_name, address1, city, province, country,
> zip, phone, name, country, default}). If you meant to render a
> collection of children, use an array instead.

and it also gives me this error:

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function.

For the above error, I'm basically doing this in my code:

```
    useEffect(() => {
          myservice.getUserProfile("USER_ID").then((response) => {
          setCustomerInfo(response.customer.default_address)
...
}, [])
```

I've also tried putting it as null:

```
const [customerInfo, setCustomerInfo] = useState(null);
```

but got the same error i.e. *Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys...*

So, how do I parse it?

Comment: What are you doing with given data in JSX part of component?

Comment: @LukaDumančić I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. Could you please elaborate, I'm a bit new to the whole react-native dev?

Comment: This error occurs during rendering. Can you include the jsx where you render customerInfo please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are trying to then map "shippingAddress"?

keep

```
const [customerInfo, setCustomerInfo] = useState([]);
```

and then

```
{shippingAddress.map((value, index) => {
    return(
    <p key={index}>{value.name}</p> //use this to adjust what you want to display
    )

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just try your code in my local space ,

I can't really see a problem in your code i only change the type of your declaration in the state to null so they can take any type of data you are giving to them so try this :

```
  const [customerInfo, setCustomerInfo] = useState(null);
  const [shippingAddress, setShippingAddress] = useState(null);
```

Comment: Putting it null also didn't work. I've updated my questions with more information, please check and see if this helps in clearing the problem a bit more.